# How to get Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID value without code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I am basically making a business to business `android application`, and to prevent other people from using my app I decided to use the `android secure ID`, which I used this code to get:

```
String androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

I was just wondering if there is any way for the client to get that `ID` themselves before download the `app`? Can it be found in the settings somewhere or is that not possible?

I tried to read a lot of articles online about this but couldn't find anything useful, thanks!

Comment: Note that _"On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher versions of the platform, a 64-bit number (expressed as a hexadecimal string), unique to each combination of **app-signing key**, user, and device. Values of ANDROID_ID are scoped by signing key and user"_. So the `ANDROID_ID` your app will get is not known until you've actually installed the app (unless maybe if the user already has some other app installed that is also signed with the same key).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this answer will be of some help to you,
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35659/where-can-i-find-the-android-id-on-my-device. The topmost answer says the following

You can do this via adb. Does not require root

```
shell@android:/ $ content query --uri content://settings/secure --projection value --where "name='android_id'"              


Row: 0 value=<your ID in hexadecimal>
```